# Flutter Syncfusion Calendar CalendarView getters are not found

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

The problem I am having is that the CalendarView getter, month, does not seem to exist even though the getters show up in the android studio autofill. I reinstalled the package syncfusion package but I can't seem to figure out why none of the getters exist for CalendarView. And just to be clear the package is successfully installed. I can't seem to find anyone else on the internet with this problem. Thank you for any help, here's the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';


class CalendarView extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const CalendarView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: const Text('Settings',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          )
      ),
      body: SfCalendar(
        view: CalendarView.month,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named your widget `CalendarView` with the same name as the one in the [syncfusion_flutter_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_calendar) package. Rename it to, for example, `MyCalendarView`

Something like this:

```dart
class MyCalendarView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCalendarView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: const Text('Settings',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          )
      ),
      body: SfCalendar(
        view: CalendarView.month,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or import the package with a prefix like this:

```dart
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart' as sf;
```

And access `SfCalendar` and `CalendarView` with the `sf` prefix:

```dart
      body: sf.SfCalendar(
        view: sf.CalendarView.month,
      ),
```